# Insert default entity from enum

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I want to insert a default value to the `status` column in my table when a new record gets created. Here is my Entity class column definition.

Cost.java

```
@Column(nullable=false)
private FinanceStatusEnum status = FinanceStatusEnum.Inputter;
```

And this is my DTO definition.

CostDTO.java

```
@JsonProperty("status")
private FinanceStatusEnum status;
```

I'm still getting `Column 'status' cannot be null` error while performing the insert. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever try to debug your code to see what is going on? I bet that your DTO just has a null status and you are blindly copying the value over to your entity which then obviously blows up due to your not-null constraint. Just set the default value on the entity in case the value is null before persisting the object.

Comment: I was having an impression that setting the default value at entity would work even if the "status" in my JSON is null (since i'm not sending it via request) but looks like that is not the case.

Comment: What you are setting on the entity there is the default java object field value i.e. the one that is initialized after constructing the java object. Hibernate knows nothing about this and since DTO mapping happens after construction (obviously), whatever DTO mapper you are using will overwrite all existing values.